# WebClient Request in Console Application doesn't hit method when published

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webclient

The basic setup is this: I have an MVC application that starts up a console application based on user input. Suffice to say, at the end of the console application's code, I'm trying to make a web request to notify the system that the console application has finished execution. Now, when I'm debugging and running locally, I hit the web API method no problem.

However, when I publish the MVC application and copy it over to the server (in the respective `wwwroot` folder, it ceases to work.

The code for generating the request is relatively simple:

```
public void SendRequest(Uri uri)
{
    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
        // previously I was sending data, but this works locally regardless of the last parameter
        // also, an example of a URI would be something like 'http://localhost:666/Ctrl/SomeFunction' though 'Ctrl' is replaced by the name of the controller
        client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, "POST", new NameValueCollection());
    }
}
```

Then the endpoint function is pretty barebones (for the sake of the question mostly):

```
public JsonResult SomeFunction()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

I have logging code around the web request to see if it threw any exceptions, and other debugging code in the controller method as well. It doesn't throw any errors, doesn't run into any exceptions, and works fine locally. I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing.

As far as avoiding any SSL errors, it was suggested by a team member that I use
`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;`. I know it's far from ideal, and should generally be avoided, but for now, it'll have to do.

**UPDATE:** I used UploadValues and checked the response. It comes back with some HTML that seems like an authentication redirect. So now the idea is to figure out how to exclude that route from authentication. So far the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on the controller hasn't been helpful (or messing around with the `[Authorize]` attributes in general). The suggestion I was given by a team member was to remove authorization for that controller action in the Startup.Auth.Cs file. I'm not sure if there's a better way for that or not. I might post a second question in regards to that.

Comment: Are you updating your URI to point to the IIS website when you deploy the console app? What are the bindings on your hosted website in IIS?

Comment: @ryancdotnet that is correct

Comment: You aren't awaiting `UploadValuesAsync` which means `WebClient` is disposed before the method has a chance to execute. Change `void SendRequest` to `async Task SendRequest` and await *it* in turn

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated the question with some more information. Even with a synchronous call it wasn't working. The issue is with permissions.

Comment: @Dortimer that only takes care of *one* bug. The next problem is that you have no idea whether the call worked or not because UploadValues doesn't return a response. Just don't use WebClient, it's obsolete. Use HttpClient with PostAsync and check the response. What status code do you get? The server will send a 401 or 403 if authentication is wrong

Comment: @Dortimer in any case use Fiddler or a similar debugging proxy to see what's actually being sent and returned

Answer (score 0):

> at the end of the console application's code, I'm trying to make a web request

May be it's because local request is fast enough to be performed right before console application is closed, but not when it's published?

Try `await client.UploadValuesTaskAsync(uri, "POST", new NameValueCollection());` or `client.UploadValues(uri, "POST", new NameValueCollection());` It should not let console application shut down before request is over.

Comment: I was using that for a while with the same results (working fine locally and not elsewhere). `UploadValuesTaskAsync` is the desired call at the end of the day though.

Comment: Did you try synchronous version `UploadValues` ? You need to log if request gets its response.

Comment: You really need to `await` that call though if you're going to use the async call.  The way you have it right now creates a race condition between the UploadValuesAsync and the disposal of your `WebClient`.

Comment: @DevNoob I was previously using `UploadValues` instead of the asynchronous call, and I had the same results.